# Jackson - Update Object in Json File

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am using Jackson to write POJO to Json file.

Later on, I need to update one of the properties in the object and update the Json. One way is to recreate the whole json file again, but in my case I have a list of Objects out of which I need to change a single object.

Is there an easy way to do this?

```
//Writing to json file
try {
            mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValue(file, pipelinesFromFile);
            } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



//Reading back again
Pipeline[] pipelinesFromFile = null;
            try {
                pipelinesFromFile = mapper.readValue(file, Pipeline[].class);
            } catch (JsonParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                pipelinesFromFile = new Pipeline[0];
            } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                pipelinesFromFile = new Pipeline[0];
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                pipelinesFromFile = new Pipeline[0];
            }

//Making changes to one of the object
pipelinesFromFile[0].someProp = "updated value"
```

Now what should the next step be?

Comment: Do you have a cached copy of the object you are modifying ? If so , you can consider revising the data and writing it back again

Comment: Not really, I need to modify it in a get request, so I guess I need to read the file everytime, get the object and update and save.

Comment: Also, I am looking for some way to not rewrite the whole json file again after every modification, if that is possible